# Is there a way to set the landing page of variations [without customizations]?

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, variations, managed-navigation, landing-page

I know by default, when users navigate to the Variation Root Site, they are redirected to the appropriate top site of a variation label, based on the language setting of their Web browser. For example, if a user's default browser language is French, SharePoint Server 2013 redirects that user to the top site of the French variation label. Is there a way to make sure everyone starts with the same language despite their Regional Browser Settings ?

I know [Benjamin Niaulin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/08/05/overview-of-sharepoint-2013-multilingual-features.aspx) talked about it but it doesn't work like this:

> One way to make sure everyone starts with the same language despite
>   their Regional Browser Settings is to set it via the Central
>   Administration in the User Profile Service Application. Of course
>   going through each individual profile could be long, you look into
>   PowerShell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic is contained in VariationRoot.aspx which by default redirects users according to language and cookie settings by means of a custom control in the page layout (VariationRootPageLayout.aspx).

You have a number of options for customising this logic if required, including replacing the custom control or adding some client-side logic using JavaScript, or changing the Welcome page for the variations root site.

If they are all going to the same start page regardless, you could just change the welcome page of the root site to point them directly at the chosen language site landing page and not use VariationRoot.aspx at all.

More general information on customising at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms562040%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (2010 but still relevant).